Help me find how the RFID copier writes the values in the tag
At first it may seems that it uses ascii but the values don't match.
The numbers 1-15 seem to written in the first nibble(without knowing what the rest bits mean)
For higher values i don't have a clue.
The data received seems to be correct because the header is always right.
Before the header and after the data received there are many zeros.
I don’t have any information on the RFID writer I use. Is a generic Chinese with no documentation. The tag is the EM4305. And the reader I use is based on EM4095 in read only config.



Data
Header
Written Value on Tag




00000000 00110001
0111111111
0000000001


00000000 01010010
0111111111
0000000002


00000000 01100011
0111111111
0000000003


00000000 10010100
0111111111
0000000004


00000001 00101001
0111111111
0000000009


00000001 01001010
0111111111
0000000010


00000001 11101111
0111111111
0000000015


00001100 01010001
0111111111
0000000050


00010011 01111111
0111111111
0000000075


00011000 01100101
0111111111
0000000099




when dealing with binary data, stop using decimal notation ... use hexadecimal or binary notation ... keep the decimal values only as comments

@jsotola the decimals are just number I put to the RFID writer to write in the tag. The keypad has only decimals.

Investigating the values you show I assume this encoding, with bit numbered from 15 (the left most) to 0 (the right most).

Bits 15 and 14 are unknown. In your examples they are always zero. It could be an bit of the value and its parity.
Bits 13 to 10 are the bits 7 to 4 of the value.
Bit 9 is the parity bit for bits 13 to 10, making parity even.
Bits 8 to 5 are the bits 3 to 0 of the value.
Bit 4 is the parity bit for bits 8 to 5, making parity even.
Bits 3 to 0 are the XOR result of bits 13 to 10 and bits 8 to 5.




15 & 14
13 to 10
9
8 to 5
4
3 to 0
binary
decimal




00
0000
0
0001
1
0001
00000001
1


00
0000
0
0010
1
0010
00000010
2


00
0000
0
0011
0
0011
00000011
3


00
0000
0
0100
1
0100
00000100
4


00
0000
0
1001
0
1001
00001001
9


00
0000
0
1010
0
1010
00001010
10


00
0000
0
1111
0
1111
00001111
15


00
0011
0
0010
1
0001
00110010
50


00
0100
1
1011
1
1111
01001011
75


00
0110
0
0011
0
0101
01100011
99




I think that make sense!!! the tags memory is 32 bits for each address, but I posted only the 16bits because the rest was zero. Ill do more tests with bigger numbers (the rfid copier can write up to 10 digits number). An interesting fact is that when I put 9999999999(10 digits of 9) it doesn't let me maybe it has something to do with the memory...

@arisk4 (32 bits - 4 XOR bits) / 5 bits per 4-bit data = 5 4-bit groups, giving you a maximum of 2^20 - 1 = 1048575. You might want to check that this value works, and 1048576 does not. You can try powers of 2 to find the actual usable width. -- If you extend your question with more and bigger values, I will extend my answer.
